# Is it possible to call non-static method without instance creation?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

For me it was very clear that the answer to this question is **NO**, but just today I came to the line

```
Context.setCredentials(userId, pwd.toCharArray());
```

where *setCredentials* is non-static method. Intellij IDEA highlights this as an error, thus my project wasn't compiling, however, in Eclipse everything is building fine, *how it can be*?

It is not a problem to fix the issue, but I would like to understand why this can happen. P.s. I might assume that this can be very project specific.

UPDATE

Before *setCredentials* is called there is another call happens:

```
Context.initContext()
```

where somewhere we invoke the following method:

```
synchronized private static void initContext(String connectionString) {
    if (_this == null) {
        _this = new Context(connectionString);
    }
}
```

where `this` is defined like this in the same Context class:

```
private static Context _this;
```

Seems that it might work and Eclipse shows it right if our instance is created, however, it is inside the class, really weird code.

Comment: Post the code for your `Context` object

Comment: No, it is not possible. Clean your Eclipse project, it is probably confused.

Comment: Indeed. Even creating String user; if(user == "") will produce an error. Variables have to be initiated.

Comment: Ok, I clean my project, but it still resolves everything and doesn't show an error to this line in Eclipse.

Comment: I think it is possible to pass a non static method in a lambda expression. Like, for instance, `String::length`.

Comment: Is Context a class? Even if there is a class named Context , there could be an object with name Context (may be defined in a super class). The reason for the IDE difference could be the imports, may be eclipse did not import the super-class but imported another one with an object named Context in it and did not import the actual Context class?

Comment: hevi, please, look to my answer what was actually the problem. The main thing is that in IDEA this file was included for compiling, however, in Eclipse it was not. Thus there was no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is clear **NO**, but now I will try to explain why it happened this way. In reality here there is nothing to be done about Java, it is more about the IDE, but more about ***project settings***.

The project was originally developed in Eclipse, however, during my try to build it in Intellij IDEA I didn't include the ***Eclipse project settings***, thus IDEA recognized it as sources and tried to compile. That's why it complained.

So, the thing is that in Eclipse the folder with this class was *included* in sources, however, all the files were *excluded* in the same time. Thus the compiler was not including this file and Eclipse doesn't show the error. I would like to notice that because I didn't have much experience with Eclipse it was extremely difficult to find it out plus I didn't recognize the following difference between the source files icons:

[image]

However, in Intellij IDEA it could be recognized a bit faster, I think:

[image]

I think that it is good to make a conclusion about this situation: *don't exclude any files from your source folders if you don't have very specific reason. If this code is not maintained, it is better just to remove it or move it somewhere else.*

Answer (score 0):

Clean and re-build your project. To call any non-static method you must have instance of that class.

Note : You can not access a non static variable inside any static method in Java, but reverse is fine i.e. you can access static variables or call static method from a non static method without any compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is **Yes** from java 8. This is because a concept called Method References(Lambda Expressions).

Example :
In the image if you see "*compareToIgnoreCase*" is actually a **non static** method , which I have called without actually creating an instance of String class. This concept is called Method Reference.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

That is clearly an IDE error.

Try to clean an build, make sure you dont have other errors.

You should try to not to rely blindly on the compiler messages, errors are really common both eclipse and Android Studio, even Xcode gets crazy sometimes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, if you downvote at least leave a comment explaining why, there is no way to get better if i dont know where i fail.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but your answer does not provide a solution. OP has already stated that he/she tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. Also, you state 'This is clearly an IDE error.' but you provide no explanation of what makes it so 'clearly' an IDE error. I don't personally think it is all that clear. In any case, it certainly doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Not sure if this question has a real answer, i have just tried to put some of my knowledge.

Comment: If you aren't sure there is an answer, then just make a comment, not an answer. Better yet flag the question.